# <form> Blocking actions in html

Tags: html, forms

It seems like `<form>` in the code below is blocking the interaction with the menu and the button.

```
<form style = "position:relative; left:50px; top:0px;" class="pure-form" align="left" top="20px" method="post" action="newtest.php">
   <p>
      Sort By Most
      <select name="sort" method=post action=newtest.php>
         <option value="Kills">Kills</option>
         <option value="Elo">Elo</option>
         <option value="Wins">Wins</option>
         <option value="Deaths">Deaths</option>
         <option value="Lost">Lost</option>
      </select>
      <input type="submit" name="playername" value="Sort" class="button-lightblue button-small pure-button">
   </p>
</form>
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: You have put method=post action=newtest.php in select, this needs to be in your opening form tag you don't have at all.  Please read about this, plenty of documentation and examples around.

Comment: I have this in my form, i've put them in select just to ty if it would work, but it doesen't in both ways.

Comment: What is the output you are getting? Please elaborate the issue you are facing (what do you mean by interaction)

Comment: If I try to click the button or the options menu it just doesen't work. It acts like is a static image

Answer (score 0):

`method` and `action` attributes are used with `<form>` tag and not with `<select>` tag

```
<form action="newtest.php" method="post" style = "position:relative; left:50px; top:0px;" class="pure-form" align="left" top="20px">
       <p>
          Sort By Most
          <select name="sort">
             <option value="Kills">Kills</option>
             <option value="Elo">Elo</option>
             <option value="Wins">Wins</option>
             <option value="Deaths">Deaths</option>
             <option value="Lost">Lost</option>
          </select>
          <input type="submit" name="playername" value="Sort" class="button-lightblue button-small pure-button">
       </p>
    </form>
```

Comment: I have this in my form, i've put them in select just to ty if it would work, but it doesen't in both ways.